# Time() and MYSQL Database data blank

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

I'm having trouble inserting the current time with the format of seconds in my database. I can't do `NOW()` or other alternatives because I need **seconds**. Any help would be great.

I'm using seconds because I wish to compare the seconds from when they submitted this code to when they visit the page next time.

PHP code snippet:

```
$time=time();
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (var1,var2,var3,var4,date) VALUES ('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4', '$time')");
```

This is what I got from that code in the MYSQL Database:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: What data type is column `logs`.`date`?

Comment: You have a datetime column date

Comment: is the date correctly stored to the database?

Comment: try this : $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (var1,var2,var3,var4,date) VALUES ('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4', now())");

Comment: Or change the date's column type to INT and then remove the single quotes around your `$time` variable.

Comment: Use the DATE('Y-m-d h:i:s',$time) instead of $time.

Comment: I want it in seconds UNIX_TIMESTAMP style, I don't want the date.

Comment: Then by default you should use current_timestamp in your date field, and chahge de data type to timestamp type

Comment: If you want to use unix timestamps the field type needs to be INT and not DATE or TIMESTAMP.

Comment: You don't need the time in seconds to calculate the seconds between two events. Use a `DATETIME` field, insert the time with `NOW()` and **calculate the seconds between two events as necessary**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the column in our database is of type INT and not DATE or TIMESTAMP.

time() returns # of seconds since the epoch, whereas Now() returns a Date object